# How to detect if bare variable or string

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to write a plotting function where you can pass bare column names to select which columns are plotted. I would like also to be able to specify a string as the color.

I have found that I need to use shQuote if I want to pass a string to aes_string. Now my problem is to figure out if a bare name or a string was passed.
How would I do this?

```
dat <- data.frame(
    time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)



plot_it <- function(dat, x,y, fill){
    require(rlang)
    require(ggplot2)

    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)
    fill <- enquo(fill)

    xN <- quo_name(x)
    yN <- quo_name(y)
    fillN <- quo_name(fill)

ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN, fill=fillN)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")

}
```

This works:

```
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, time)
```

This does not:

```
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, "grey")
```

Note that this requires the newest versions of rlang and ggplot2.

Comment: The second one doesn't because you are quoting it and then using `enquo` on it.  You can do that by removing the `enquo` and `quo_name` for the `fill`

Comment: Yeah I get why it is not working. What is eluding me is how to make it possible to pass a string like that while also being able to pass bare names. So I was thinking it should be possible to detect if what is passed is bare or not.

Comment: it seems to be a problem in the `aes_string` as you are passing a color and column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43977715/8406369) and [Eumenedies' answer/test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45588977/8406369), here is a version that:

- Solves your original problem
- Prevents an unnecessary legend, as Eumenedies did
- Provides ggplot object that can be added to without error
- Uses the more appropriate `geom_col`, per Eumenedies' suggestion

The main trick is that, if `fill` isn't a factor in the plot, you want it outside of the `aes` / `aes_string` block.

```
plot_it <- function(dat, x, y, fill) {

  lst <- as.list(match.call())

  xN <- quo_name(enquo(x))
  yN <- quo_name(enquo(y))

  if(is.character(lst$fill)) {
    p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN)) +
      geom_col(fill = fill)
  } else {
    p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN, fill = quo_name(enquo(fill)))) +
      geom_col()
  }

  return(p)
}

plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, time)
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, "blue")
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, "blue") + geom_point()
```

You could make the `if` block shorter by moving the `fill` aesthetic in the second case to the `geom_col` call, but that will extend in a different way if you add more geoms.

Also, once `ggplot` is updated to support `rlang`, it would be cleaner to avoid  `aes_string` and `quo_name` combination and just use `!!fill`.

Note that, assuming that the `fill` factor exists, if it's always going to be the same as the `x` factor, it would probably make more sense to have a version where `fill` is an optional argument. You would only overwrite the default per-factor color if the argument is included.

Comment: I gave the bounty to Eumenedies as I think it was the most elegant as asked for. But I marked this answer as best for the reasons stated. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: I am surprised that moving the `fill` to the `ggplot` (but outside `aes_string`) is not equivalent. Could you explain this? If it was the `geom_col` could go outside the `if` statement.

Comment: @Jan, you mean like `ggplot(data = dat, aes_string(x=Xn, y=Yn), fill = fill) + geom_col()`? While ggplot takes a dots (`...`) argument, the help says it's not currently used, which means that it wouldn't be passed to subsequent `geom_*`s. I think the idea is that the base `ggplot` function only sets up (at most) the data source and how it is associated with the plot; specific visuals (such as setting specific colors) are left to other functions.

Comment: Ah OK. I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @akrun's suggestion of how to detect which case we had (was removed) I found something that does what I asked for:

```
plot_it <- function(dat, x, y, fill) {

    lst <- as.list(match.call())

    if(is.character(lst$fill)){
        fillN <- shQuote(fill)
    } else{
        fillN <- quo_name(enquo(fill))
    }

    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)


    xN <- quo_name(x)
    yN <- quo_name(y)


    p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN, fill=fillN)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")

    return(p)
}
```

Turns out this doesn't actually do what I had in mind since it assigns the quoted value as a factor to assign colors by. Not the actual color.

I came up with this that seems to work but is not really elegant:

```
plot_it <- function(dat, x, y, fill) {

    lst <- as.list(match.call())

    if(!(type_of(lst$fill)=="symbol" | (type_of(lst$fill)=="string" & length(lst$fill)==1))) stop("Fill must either be a bare name or a vector of length 1.")

    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)

    xN <- quo_name(x)
    yN <- quo_name(y)


    if(is.character(lst$fill)){
        dat[,"fillN"] <- fill
        fillN <- fill

        p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN, fill = shQuote(fillN))) +
             scale_fill_manual(name="fill", values=setNames(fillN,fillN))
    } else{
        fillN <- quo_name(enquo(fill))

        p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN, fill = fillN))
    }



       p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity")

    return(p)
}
```

Any idea to make this a bit more elegant?

Comment: I was working on a similar kind of thing and dropped it in the middle as it was not elegant.

Answer (score 2):

So the way I did it was to use `do.call` and a list of parameters to optionally pass a parameter to the `geom_bar` function.

```
plot_it <- function(dat, x, y, fill) {

  lst <- as.list(match.call())

  xN <- quo_name(enquo(x))
  yN <- quo_name(enquo(y))
  fillN <- quo_name(enquo(fill))

  # Build the geom_bar call using do.call and a list of parameters
  # If the fill parameter is a character then the parameter list contains
  # both stat = "identity" and colour = ...; this colour will override the 
  # colour aesthetic
  p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=xN, y=yN, fill=fillN)) +
    do.call(geom_bar, c(list(stat = "identity"), list(fill = lst$fill)[is.character(lst$fill)]))

  return(p)
}

plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, time)
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, "blue")
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, 5)
```

I used `"blue"` for clarity as ggplot will default to grey anyway but it does work with any colour literal as far as I can tell. I think this is more elegant than using conditionals.

As a matter of interest, `geom_col` might be more appropriate in this context than `geom_bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for one parameter to represent two types of arguments: one naming a column, the other naming a color. The simplest solution is to just split it into two parameters and add some checks to make sure only one is supplied.

```
plot_it <- function(dat, x, y, fill_column, fill_color = NULL){
  require(rlang)
  require(ggplot2)

  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)

  xN <- quo_name(x)
  yN <- quo_name(y)

  if (!missing(fill_column) && !is.null(fill_color)) {
    stop("Specify either fill_column or fill_color, not both")
  }
  if (missing(fill_column) && is.null(fill_color)) {
    stop("Specify one of fill_column or fill_color")
  }
  plot_geom <- if (!is.null(fill_color)) {
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = fill_color)
  } else {
    fill <- enquo(fill_column)
    fillN <- quo_name(fill)
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes_string(fill = fillN))
  }

  ggplot(data = dat, aes_string(x = xN, y = yN)) +
    plot_geom
}


plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, fill_column = time)
plot_it(dat, time, total_bill, fill_color  = "grey")
```