# Guidelines for specifying variables in a function

Tags: r, function, loops, functional-programming, kruskal-wallis

Consider `dat1` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
```

`dat1` has measurements for 5 variables, and observations (`ID`s) can be grouped according to 3 grouping variables: `Loc`, `State`, and `Region`
I am having to perform various tasks on each response variable/grouping variable combination, so I have been writing functions to make it easier, and keep my analysis tidy. I am using the `rstatix` package to do several operations. The following function will conduct a Kruskal Wallis test on the data I specify, calculate the effect size `efsz` and return the results in a single data frame `res`:

```r
library(rstatix)
KruskTest <- function(dat, groupvar, var){
  kt <- dat%>%kruskal_test(get(var) ~ get(groupvar))
  efsz <- dat%>%kruskal_effsize(get(var) ~ get(groupvar))
  res <<- cbind(kt, efsz[,3:5])
  res[1,1] <<- var
  res$groupvar <<- groupvar 
  res <<- res[,c(10,1:9)]
}
KruskTest(dat=dat1, groupvar = "Region", var = "var1")
```

Now I can use that function to loop over each response variable and get the results for a grouping variable (example shows it for `Region`) in a single data frame, which is what I need:

```r
vars <- paste(names(dat1[,5:9]))
a <- data.frame()
for(i in vars){
  KruskTest(dat=dat1, groupvar="Region", var= i)
  a <- rbind(a, res)
}
```

That works great for the Kruskal Wallis test, now I want to make a very similar function that will do a duns test, but watch what happens:

```r
dunn <- function(dat, groupvar, var){
  res <<- dat%>%rstatix::dunn_test(get(var) ~ get(groupvar), p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
}
dunn(dat=dat1, groupvar="Region", var = "var1")

r:Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist. x The column `get(groupvar)` doesn't exist.
```

Outside of a user-written function, you specify data for the `dunn_test()` and `kruskal_test()` the exact same way. So what is the difference between specifying variables in these two funcitons, and why does the first one work but not the second?

Comment: This isn't what you were asking about, but you should really avoid `<<-`. Use `<-` inside your function, and then call it with `a = rbind(a, KruskTest(...))`. No one (possibly including you in 6 months) will expect your code to buck standard practice by using global assignment. And I'm sure at some point you'll have a variable named `res` in your global environment that gets accidentally overwritten when you call one of these functions.

Comment: Or maybe you'll just get annoyed if you want to save results in separate objects and you have to write `KruskTest(); a <- res; KruskTest(); b <- res` instead  of `a <-KruskTest(); b <- KruskTest()`.

Comment: As for your issue, as far as I can tell it's a typo - you used `groupvarv` with a `v` a the end.

Comment: Thank you this is good advise. And  thanks for pointing out my typo (which I went back in fixed). The corrected `dunn()` function that I wrote does not work. @Chuck P's solution using `as.formula()` fixes the issue. However, if someone doesn't care to explain; I am still curious as to why my original syntax (using `get(x)`)  worked for the first function, and not the second.

Comment: I'll investigate your old function as long as you mark my solution as accepted(able)

Comment: Good news is, it's not you or anything you did.  Bad news is the two functions deal with what's passed to them slightly differently (I peeked at the code in the github site).  Ironically I asked a related question around here this week (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091090) so I share your frustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account @Gregor 's comments about not writing to the environment and trying to clean up some other rough edges's I have a proposed improvement although Gregor is correct your biggest problem was nothing but a typo.

```r
library(rstatix)
library(purrr)

# rewritten to avoid writing to environment

NewKruskTest <- function(dat, groupvar, var) {
  kt <- dat %>% kruskal_test(as.formula(paste(var, "~", groupvar)))
  efsz <- dat %>% kruskal_effsize(as.formula(paste(var, "~", groupvar)))
  results <- cbind(kt, efsz[,3:5])
  results$groupvar <- groupvar 
  results <- results[,c(10,1:9)]
  return(results)
}

# works on a single if you want to test
# NewKruskTest(dat = dat1, groupvar = "Region", var = "var1") 

# No paste needed
vars <- names(dat1[,5:9])

# NewKruskTest will work in your existing for loop but you 
# may find `purrr:map_dfr` cleaner

map_dfr(vars, ~ NewKruskTest(dat = dat1, groupvar = "Region", var = .))
#>   groupvar  .y.   n statistic df      p         method      effsize method.1
#> 1   Region var1 200 3.0520896  1 0.0806 Kruskal-Wallis  0.010364089  eta2[H]
#> 2   Region var2 200 0.5961552  1 0.4400 Kruskal-Wallis -0.002039620  eta2[H]
#> 3   Region var3 200 1.6330090  1 0.2010 Kruskal-Wallis  0.003197015  eta2[H]
#> 4   Region var4 200 3.4031343  1 0.0651 Kruskal-Wallis  0.012137042  eta2[H]
#> 5   Region var5 200 0.7230090  1 0.3950 Kruskal-Wallis -0.001398945  eta2[H]
#>   magnitude
#> 1     small
#> 2     small
#> 3     small
#> 4     small
#> 5     small

# NewDunn rewritten

NewDunn <- function(dat, groupvar, var) {
  results <- dat %>% rstatix::dunn_test(as.formula(paste(var, "~", groupvar)), 
                        p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
  results$groupvar <- groupvar 
  results <- results[,c(10,1:9)]
  return(results)
}

# works on a single if you want to test
# NewDunn(dat=dat1, groupvar ="Region", var = "var1")

map_dfr(vars, ~ NewDunn(dat = dat1, groupvar = "Region", var = .))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>   groupvar .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p  p.adj p.adj.signif
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 Region   var1  r1     r2       100   100    -1.75  0.0806 0.0806 ns          
#> 2 Region   var2  r1     r2       100   100    -0.772 0.440  0.440  ns          
#> 3 Region   var3  r1     r2       100   100    -1.28  0.201  0.201  ns          
#> 4 Region   var4  r1     r2       100   100     1.84  0.0651 0.0651 ns          
#> 5 Region   var5  r1     r2       100   100    -0.850 0.395  0.395  ns
```

based on your data

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
```